# Booting memtest86 with kexec

Tags: boot, chromebook, memtest86+

I have a Chromebook (Samsung Series 5) that does not have a BIOS and cannot boot from USB.

From recent random crashes, I am suspecting that the RAM is broken, and would like to run memtest86.

I installed Ubuntu on it via [these instructions](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.de/2012/08/update-chrubuntu-1204-now-works-on-cr.html).

Is it possible to boot into memtest86 using kexec?

I tried `sudo kexec /usr/lib/memtest86+/memtest86+.elf` but only get `Invalid memory segment 0x5000 - 0x2ffff`.

If not, do you have any other idea how I can get memtest booted on this device?